# Incorrect column name for pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I was trying to create pivot table from my query 
when i choose select * from it works fine but when i tries to select columns as shown in below code it gives me error Incorrect column name

```
 select sr,PayDescr,PayMonAmt from (select sr= case when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='GS' then  1
                when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='BS' then  2
                when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='HA' then  3
                when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='TA' then  4
                when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='FA' then  5
                else 6 end
, PayDescr = rtrim(Ctname.Descr),SUM(PayMonAmt) as PayMonAmt  from 
maEmpPay mn
outer apply(
        select Descr,PayCat from maPayCat pc
        where mn.PayCat = pc.PayCat
        )Ctname
where  EmpID = mn.EmpID group by Ctname.Descr, Ctname.PayCat)   pv 
 pivot
 (
 sum (PayMonAmt) for PayDescr IN ([Basic Salary],[Food Allowance],[Tuition 
 Allowance],[Transportation Allowance])
 ) AS e
```

the working code

```
 select * from (  select sr= case when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='GS' then  1
                when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='BS' then  2
                when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='HA' then  3
                when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='TA' then  4
                when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='FA' then  5
                else 6 end
, PayDescr = rtrim(Ctname.Descr),SUM(PayMonAmt) as PayMonAmt  from 
maEmpPay mn
outer apply(
        select Descr,PayCat from maPayCat pc
        where mn.PayCat = pc.PayCat
        )Ctname where  EmpID = mn.EmpID group by Ctname.Descr, Ctname.PayCat
)   pv 
 pivot
 (
 sum (PayMonAmt) for PayDescr IN ([Basic Salary],[Food Allowance],[Tuition 
 Allowance],[Transportation Allowance])
 ) AS e
```

Comment: This doesn't look like MySQL syntax: is `mysql` the correct database code for your question?

Comment: Yeah, `pivot` is a Microsoft SQL Server thing. I see a lot of developers tag their question incorrectly on Stack Overflow, tagging it [tag:mysql] when they should use [tag:sql-server].

Comment: tag updated to Sql Server

Comment: For sure you didn't get those columns when you use `SELECT *`. Try it again and see what's the column names it returns.

Comment: Sami i am getting perfect pivot fro Select * statement but not with column names.. Any suggestions

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'PayDescr'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'PayMonAmt'.

Comment: The SQL code you posted in the question seems to be missing a lot of brackets. Can you post the actual code you're having problems with?

Comment: Check to make sure that Is  'PayDescr' is only getting returned once.  If it's returned twice, you now have a result with duplicate column name, which normally isn't allowed.

Comment: Actually i am trying create pivot for below code
` select sr= case when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='GS' then  1
     when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='BS' then  2
     when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='HA' then  3
     when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='TA' then  4
     when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='FA' then  5
     else 6 end
 , PayDescr = rtrim(Ctname.Descr),SUM(PayMonAmt) as PayMonAmt  from 
 maEmpPay mn
 outer apply(
   select Descr,PayCat from maPayCat pc
   where mn.PayCat = pc.PayCat
   )Ctname
 where  EmpID = mn.EmpID
group by Ctname.Descr, Ctname.PayCat `

Comment: its return single column for PayDescr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got solution

```
SELECT
sr,
[Basic Salary],
[Food Allowance],
[Tuition Allowance],
[Transportation Allowance] FROM (
SELECT
    sr = CASE
        when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='GS' then  1
        when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='BS' then  2
        when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='HA' then  3
        when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='TA' then  4
        when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='FA' then  5
        else 6
    END,
    PayDescr = rtrim(Ctname.Descr),
    SUM(PayMonAmt) as PayMonAmt
FROM
    maEmpPay As mn
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT Descr, PayCat 
        FROM maPayCat pc
        WHERE mn.PayCat = pc.PayCat
    ) As Ctname


WHERE
    EmpID = mn.EmpID 

GROUP BY
    Ctname.Descr, 
    Ctname.PayCat) PIVOT(
SUM(PayMonAmt) FOR PayDescr IN 
(
    [Basic Salary],
    [Food Allowance],
    [Tuition Allowance],
    [Transportation Allowance]
)) As e
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is pivot query so remove PayMonAmt and add [Basic Salary],[Food Allowance],[Tuition 
 Allowance],[Transportation Allowance]. Let me know if your query is still unresolved:

```
    select sr,PayDescr,[Basic Salary],[Food Allowance],[Tuition Allowance],[Transportation Allowance] from 
          (select sr= case when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='GS' then  1 when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='BS' then  2
            when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='HA' then  3
            when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='TA' then  4
            when rtrim(Ctname.PayCat)='FA' then  5
            else 6 end , PayDescr = rtrim(Ctname.Descr),SUM(PayMonAmt) as PayMonAmt  
            from maEmpPay mn
            outer apply(
    select Descr,PayCat from maPayCat pc
    where mn.PayCat = pc.PayCat
    )Ctname
    where  EmpID = mn.EmpID group by Ctname.Descr, Ctname.PayCat)   pv 
    pivot
    (
     sum (PayMonAmt) for PayDescr IN ([Basic Salary],[Food Allowance],[Tuition Allowance],[Transportation Allowance])) AS e
```